# Is there a way to figure out what cities have wonders?

Tags: civilization-5

I'm a bit of a wonder perfectionist in Civilization, and I like to have a monopoly on them. However, sometimes another civilization sneaks one by me; in those situations, I like to conquer the city that has it to complete my collection.

In previous versions of Civilization, you had the ability, through demographics, to figure out what cities had wonders. But I can't seem to find anything like that in Civilization 5: the closest things I've found are the periodic "top 10"-style lists that'll mention how many wonders a civilization has.

Is there better way to figure out exactly which foreign cities have wonders?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A lot of wonders (if not all of them?) show up as a visible model around the city in which they are constructing / constructed. So if you see a pyramid around a city, you know the the great pyramid is built there.

It takes some practice to know what wonder is what, and it's definitely a very crude way; requires scanning all cities for things that are sometimes very hard to notice. But it does work, I use this method often to know which wonder is being constructed by other civilizations, to avoid working on the same wonder.

Notice that all wonders have different "under construction" and "completed" models.

**EDIT:** I've found [this wonderful page](http://well-of-souls.com/civ/civ5_wonders.html) which attempts to catalog all wonders with screenshots of their "under construction" and "completed" models. Still incomplete, but useful nonetheless.

Comment: Should you be able to see the models even when the cities are masked via fog of war (i.e. explored, but no friendly units nearby)?

Comment: @Mark I think that new models will not appear until you have the area visible again, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 11):

It won't tell you exactly which city they are in, but if you go to the Diplomacy Summary and choose "Global Politics", it will show you which wonders each civilization has.  I believe you need to have met the civilization at some point in order to see them here.

I also noticed that when you get the message that another civ has built a wonder, the city that completed the wonder will flash on your minimap, presuming that you have explored it at some point (you do not need visibility at the time of completion).

Comment: All these methods will only give you information _after_ the wonder has been built.